# C# sdk. OAuth dialog returning token in hashstring

Tags: c#, facebook

Why am I getting the access token in the hashstring when redirected back from the facebook OAuth dialog requesting for permission?

Here's the code I use to construct the facebook OAuth dialog:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "response_type", "code_and_token" },
                        { "redirect_uri", "http://localhost:3434/"},
                        { "scope", string.Join(",", scopes)}
                    };

            return oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters).AbsoluteUri;
```

And it redirects to:

http://localhost:3434/?name=asdf%3F#access_token=162925373763120|2.qLDBCyZRe1gGOvrpjLIouQ__.3600.1305252000.1-100000956820295|Hx6tBpndm5Dm1BAXVxjo7QcoxLs&expires_in=5998&code=jTu2wOzMadW0xRm47LgQZlMiu2cWqIzG20BkGNov7Rs.eyJpdiI6IldjRjVaUTF2RjgzUXJsWjNGR1dnWHcifQ.1nmIBbttrglCioBC3uUQeQ_2btjEfj7acprwzc4E12Ap36GxUoAoVwIqyQFF91ghKi_whzSltd_VVr4nMbyGv0T3wvQ-hLfxhS4F3saZv94ubzDq_gKcvdG9BXMZG77FlY1QP7SLOpdIP4yh8mNWEw

How am I supposed to retrieve the access_token after the OAuth dialog redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit- with CBroe's answer

the problem is this line:
{ "response_type", "code_and_token" }

it can only either be:
{ "response_type", "token" }
When set to token, the access_token is passed back in the **hashstring** which means it can only be used for javascript.

or

{ "response_type", "code" }
When set to code, the access_code is passed back in the querystring. This querystring is then used to swap with facebook for the access_token. (Which is the same access_token retrieved from the hashstring if response_type is set to "token"

Comment: _I_ rather can’t belive, that no one has commented yet on `"code_and_token"`, which is of course __not__ a valid value for the `response_type` parameter – it is either `code` __or__ `token`. (And since `code` is the default value, this nonsense value given here makes it just fall back to that.) Making up one’s own funny little values that contradict what the docs clearly state is seldom a good idea …

Comment: yes. that { "response_type", "code_and_token" } none sense was a gift from the tech director who had no clue.